# Django segmentation fault when querying model within runserver

Tags: python, django, segmentation-fault

What could cause Django to see fault when querying a model within run server, but that same model can be queried exactly the same way within the interactive shell and not see fault?

Here is my segmentation fault traceback using the faulthandler module within the standard library:

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault
```

Current thread 0x00007f8e533cb700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 307 in get_new_connection
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194 in connect
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216 in ensure_connection
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232 in _cursor
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255 in cursor
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 577 in temporary_connection
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59 in **enter**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 390 in sql_server_version
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37 in **get**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/compiler.py", line 176 in as_sql
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1052 in execute_sql
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54 in **iter**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186 in _fetch_all
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 268 in **iter**
  File "/home/myUser/Projects/myProject/ReportApp/api/reports.py", line 213 in get
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492 in dispatch
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68 in view
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54 in wrapped_view
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124 in _get_response
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34 in inner
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34 in inner
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34 in inner
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34 in inner
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34 in inner
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34 in inner
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34 in inner
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34 in inner
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 91 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34 in inner
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 78 in get_response
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 142 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 65 in **call**
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137 in run
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194 in handle_one_request
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169 in handle
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681 in **init**
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354 in finish_request
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625 in process_request_thread
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862 in run
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007f8e59eae700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 376 in select
  File "/home/myUser/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 232 in serve_forever
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 213 in run
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 139 in inner_run
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225 in wrapper

Thread 0x00007f8e626c2700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 279 in reloader_thread
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 302 in python_reloader
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 323 in main
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102 in run
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95 in handle
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353 in execute
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60 in execute
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316 in run_from_argv
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 375 in execute
  File "/home/myUser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv-vCGrYWCJ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 381 in execute_from_command_line
  File "manage.py", line 15 in 
Segmentation fault

I am running openSuse Linux, python 3.5.4, and Django 2.1.5, with SQL Server as the database. Here are the modules that I have in my environment:

atomicwrites            1.2.1

attrs                   18.2.0

Django                  2.1.5

django-cors-headers     2.4.0

django-multiselectfield 0.1.8

django-pyodbc-azure     2.1.0.0

djangorestframework     3.9.1

djangorestframework-jwt 1.11.0

gunicorn                19.9.0

more-itertools          5.0.0

pathlib2                2.3.3

Pillow                  5.4.1

pip                     19.0.1

pluggy                  0.8.1

psycopg2                2.7.7

py                      1.7.0

PyJWT                   1.7.1

pyodbc                  4.0.25

pytest                  4.1.1

pytz                    2018.9

reportlab               3.5.13

setuptools              40.6.3

six                     1.12.0

wheel                   0.32.3

XlsxWriter              1.1.2

I have tried removing and reinstalling the Pipenv environment, but it is still throwing this segmentation fault. I can query the models within the routine that keeps throwing the segmentation fault from within the Django interactive shell just fine without throwing a seg fault. Really weird.

Comment: It would help a lot If you add the stack trace to your question. Also if you post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Probably nothing besides a really bad installation. Are you sure this is a segmentation fault?